# Why does UI sometimes fail to update in recyclerview with data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have a list of 5 elements in a recyclerview, set up like a to do list. There is a listener on the checkbox in each row, and for the purposes of this minimal reproducible example whenever you check any boxes it randomly sets the value of the 5 checkboxes. When an item is unchecked, it should appear in black text, and when an item is checked it should appear in gray text and italic.

When I check a box and reset the values, usually the UI updates as expected. However, sometimes one item sticks in the wrong layout so the checkbox shows the correct value but the text style is wrong. Why is this behavior inconsistent and how can I ensure the UI is refreshed every time?

Here's the entire MRE:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.dalydays.android.mre_recyclerview_refresh_last_item.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ToDoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.itemsList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val onCheckboxClickListener: (ToDoItem) -> Unit = { _ ->
            adapter.submitList(getSampleList())
        }

        adapter = ToDoAdapter(onCheckboxClickListener)

        binding.itemsList.adapter = adapter

        adapter.submitList(getSampleList())
    }

    private fun getSampleList(): List<ToDoItem> {
        val sampleList = mutableListOf<ToDoItem>()

        sampleList.add(ToDoItem(id=1, description = "first item", completed = Random.nextBoolean()))
        sampleList.add(ToDoItem(id=2, description = "second item", completed = Random.nextBoolean()))
        sampleList.add(ToDoItem(id=3, description = "third item", completed = Random.nextBoolean()))
        sampleList.add(ToDoItem(id=4, description = "fourth item", completed = Random.nextBoolean()))
        sampleList.add(ToDoItem(id=5, description = "fifth item", completed = Random.nextBoolean()))

        return sampleList
    }
}
```

**ToDoItem.kt**

```
data class ToDoItem(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var description: String,
    var completed: Boolean = false
)
```

**ToDoAdapter.kt**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.dalydays.android.mre_recyclerview_refresh_last_item.databinding.ChecklistItemCheckedBinding
import com.dalydays.android.mre_recyclerview_refresh_last_item.databinding.ChecklistItemUncheckedBinding

const val ITEM_UNCHECKED = 0
const val ITEM_CHECKED = 1

class ToDoAdapter(private val onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit): ListAdapter<ToDoItem, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ToDoItemDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_CHECKED -> ViewHolderChecked.from(parent)
            else -> ViewHolderUnchecked.from(parent)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val toDoItem = getItem(position)
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderChecked -> {
                holder.bind(toDoItem, onCheckboxClick)
            }
            is ViewHolderUnchecked -> {
                holder.bind(toDoItem, onCheckboxClick)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val toDoItem = getItem(position)
        return when (toDoItem.completed) {
            true -> ITEM_CHECKED
            else -> ITEM_UNCHECKED
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderChecked private constructor(private val binding: ChecklistItemCheckedBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(toDoItem: ToDoItem, onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit) {
            binding.todoItem = toDoItem
            binding.checkboxCompleted.setOnClickListener {
                onCheckboxClick(toDoItem)
            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolderChecked {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                return ViewHolderChecked(ChecklistItemCheckedBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            }
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderUnchecked private constructor(private val binding: ChecklistItemUncheckedBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(toDoItem: ToDoItem, onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit) {
            binding.todoItem = toDoItem
            binding.checkboxCompleted.setOnClickListener {
                onCheckboxClick(toDoItem)
            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolderUnchecked {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                return ViewHolderUnchecked(ChecklistItemUncheckedBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            }
        }
    }
}


class ToDoItemDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ToDoItem>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <data>

        </data>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/items_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**checklist_item_checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="todoItem"
            type="com.dalydays.android.mre_recyclerview_refresh_last_item.ToDoItem" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_completed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:checked="@{todoItem.completed}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@{todoItem.description}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="#65000000"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox_completed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Mow the lawn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**checklist_item_unchecked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="todoItem"
            type="com.dalydays.android.mre_recyclerview_refresh_last_item.ToDoItem" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_completed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:checked="@{todoItem.completed}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@{todoItem.description}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox_completed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Mow the lawn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `adapter.submitList`?

Comment: @dominicoder Check this article: https://medium.com/simform-engineering/listadapter-a-recyclerview-adapter-extension-5359d13bd879

Comment: As Chintan Soni hinted, the implementation is part of the Recyclerview.Listadapter library, not one that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the "best" solution, but this is what I came up with. I determined that there is probably an issue with the timing between the checkbox animation and the recyclerview refresh animation. Sometimes, depending on how long it takes the recyclerview to diff, the recyclerview can attempt to refresh before or after the checkbox finishes animating. When it finishes before, the checkbox animation blocks the recyclerview animation and leaves the UI in the wrong state. Otherwise it appears to work as intended.

I decided to manually run `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` even though `RecyclerView.ListAdapter` is supposed to handle this automatically. It still animates somewhat inconsistently depending on when the diff finishes calculating, but it's much better than leaving the UI in a bad state, and it's much better than refreshing the entire list every time with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In MainActivity, change the checkboxlistener to this:

```
val onCheckboxClickListener: (ToDoItem, Int) -> Unit = { _, position ->
    adapter.submitList(getSampleList())
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
}
```

In ToDoAdapter, change class header to this:

```
class ToDoAdapter(private val onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem, Int) -> Unit): ListAdapter<ToDoItem, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ToDoItemDiffCallback()) {
```

And change both bind() functions to this:

```
fun bind(toDoItem: ToDoItem, onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem, Int) -> Unit) {
    binding.todoItem = toDoItem
    binding.checkboxCompleted.setOnClickListener {
        onCheckboxClick(toDoItem, layoutPosition)
    }
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify these methods

```
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
    return ((oldItem.id == newItem.id) && (oldItem.description == newItem.description) && (oldItem.completed == newItem.completed) 
}
```

Also override the methods `getNewListSize()` & `getOldListSize()`

Comment: First thing: How does this help? Second thing: You are referring to old implementation. To learn the new way, check out this article: https://medium.com/simform-engineering/listadapter-a-recyclerview-adapter-extension-5359d13bd879

Comment: @ChintanSoni In my previous project when i was passing the new list it was not getting refreshed, i had to write conditions like this, because arecontentssame was returning true all the time.

Comment: Data class, by default implement "equals" method. We don't need to write it manually.

Comment: I have tried this, but get the same results. Again, the issue is not that the recyclerview doesn't update, it's only that it's inconsistent. Usually it updates, but sometimes does not, so I don't think it's an issue with how diff is calculated, but maybe some kind of race condition.

Comment: @ChintanSoni I think Manoj is right...in my case, I extended `LiveData`, and implemented an `equals` and `hashCode` for them to check for structural equality...it was a mistake, because sometimes, I would `submitList` new item models where `areContentsTheSame` is true of some of the item models, causing the `ViewHolder` to not be re-bound to the updated item model. Although the models are structurally equal, the `LiveData` instances were different, causing the UI to not update properly, because it is still observing the old, stale `LiveData`. My fix was to stop overriding `hashCode` & `equals`